# Flash plugin download problem

Tags: command-line, flash, downloads, plugins

So when I start installing flash player from software center , it gives an error saying that it couldnt download flash plugin.
"The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

flashplugin-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection."

Comment: Rather than installing flashplugin-installer, install the adobe-flashplugin package from partner repository

Answer (score 0):

A handy way for installing Flash (Adobe) into your system:

- go to Adobe-site and download the newest Flashplayer for Linux (choose the tar.gz package)
- unpack the package in 'downloads' so you can detect a singel file named: **libflashplayer.so**
- press ALT + F2 and type **gksudo nautilus** press enter and prompt your password
- navigate in the core to **usr/lib/mozilla/plugins**
- copy and paste the file you've unpacked in downloads (libflashplayer.so)
- close all windows including Firefox (if that was open)
- restart Firefox and go to a site that has some movies in Flash to watch for testing.

That's all, you should have a good running Flash with this work-arround.

Should you run Xubuntu it is then gksudo thunar instead of nautilus ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be for only installing the flash-player. But I always install ubuntu-restricted-extras anyways and that fixes things for me.